# octahedron (Polyhedron) on LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to create an octahedron (Polyhedron) in a coordinate system. Two corner points should lie on one of the axes, one of the two passing through (0,0,0).

Could you help me?

I dont Know how to name the corner points (A,..,F) and create the coordinate system.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{point}=[circle,thick,draw=black,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=4pt,minimum height=4pt]
    \node (a)[point] at (0,0) {};
    \node (b)[point] at (2,0) {};
    \node (c)[point] at (3,1) {};
    \node (d)[point] at (1,1) {};
    \node (e)[point] at (1.5,3) {};
    \node (f)[point] at (1.5,-2) {};
    \draw (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (c.center) -- (e.center) -- (b.center);
    \draw (a.center) -- (e.center);
    \draw[dashed] (a.center) -- (d.center) -- (c.center);
    \draw[dashed] (d.center) -- (e.center);

    \draw (a.center) -- (f.center) -- (b.center);
    \draw (f.center) -- (c.center);
    \draw[dashed] (f.center) -- (d.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 2):

run with `xelatex` or with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}   
\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=30 10 10 rtp2xyz, lightsrc=10 5 4,Decran=30}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(5,5)
\psSolid[object=octahedron,a=3,linecolor=blue,fillcolor=Turquoise,action=draw*]%
\axesIIID(3,3,3)(5,4,4) 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]